# “Undefined variable: a ” in laravel 5.2 view

Tags: variables, laravel-5, undefined

Help me please im a newbie using laravel, when I am using Relations,I am getting an error as bellow..

> ErrorException in 5ef4934eeff3d728094534ae49b02bc13ec04ae1.php line 122:
>   Undefined variable: a (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\beasiswa\resources\views\beasiswa\daftar_beasiswa.blade.php)

**Controller** is in BeasiswaController.php

```html
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Beasiswa;
use App\Databeasiswa;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Controllers\BeasiswaController;

class BeasiswaController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
     $data = Beasiswa::all();
        return view('beasiswa.daftar_beasiswa')->with('data', $data);
    }
```

**Route** is defined like this

```html
Route::resource('/beasiswa', 'BeasiswaController');
Route::get('beasiswa', 'BeasiswaController@index');
```

And this is my **Models** Beasiswa.php

```html
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Beasiswa extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
       'nama_bea', 
       'syarat', 
       'waktu_pendaftaran',
       'status'
       ];

 public function callDatabeasiswa(){
  return $this->hasMany('App\Databeasiswa');
 }
}
```

And this is my **View** on daftar_beasiswa.blade.php

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 20px">No</th>
      <th>Nama Beasiswa</th> 
      <th>Periode Pendaftaran</th>                
      <th style="width: 45px">Edit</th>
      <th style="width: 45px">Detail</th>
      <th style="width: 45px">Hapus</th>
      <th style="width: 45px">Broadcast</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
 @foreach($data as $a)
 <tr>
  <td>{{ $a->id }}</td>
  <td>{{ $a->nama_bea }}</td>
  <td>{{ $a->waktu_pendaftaran }}</td>
  <td>
   <a href="{{ url('beasiswa/'.$a->id.'/edit') }}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>
  </td>
  <td>
   <a href="{{ url('beasiswa/'.$a->id) }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></a>
  </td>
  <td>
   <form action="{{ url('beasiswa/'.$a->id) }}" method="post">
   {{ csrf_field() }}
   <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>
   </form>
  </td>
  <!-- POST -->
  <td>
    <!-- BUTTON SEND VIA TELEGRAM -->
   {{ csrf_field() }}
   <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-sendtelegram" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></i></button>
  </td>
 </tr>
 @endforeach
</tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you're sending your data as session data using the ->with() function. Better to just serve it to your view. Second you're basically sending the data with arbitrary identifiers.

The $data is expected to be an array - where the keys will turn into variables that you can access in your view. It's really clever.

So if you do this in your controller:

```
$data = ['name' => 'Mr. Smith', 'models' => MyModel::all()];
return view('myview', $data);
```

You can acces the data like this in your view:

```
<p>{{ $name }}</p>

@foreach($models as $model)

 <p>{{ $model->myAttribute }}</p>

@endforeach
```

So in your case, try doing something like this instead:

```
 // In your controller
 public function index() {
        $data = ['beasiswa' => Beasiswa::all()];
        return view('beasiswa.daftar_beasiswa', $data);
    }
```

and then

```
   // in your view
    @foreach($beasiswa as $a)
    ....
```